# name 'BoundMetaData' is not defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got the tutorial

> http://www.rmunn.com/sqlalchemy-tutorial/tutorial.html

When I compile got the error message

```
The debugged program raised the exception unhandled NameError
"name 'BoundMetaData' is not defined"
```

I am use the latest sqlAlchemy .

How Could I fixed this?

After read this  I modified to my own for latest version sqlAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:mypassword@localhost/mysql')
metadata = MetaData()
users = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(40)),
    Column('age', Integer),
    Column('password', String),
)
metadata.create_all(engine) 
i = users.insert()
i.execute(name='Mary', age=30, password='secret')
i.execute({'name': 'John', 'age': 42},
          {'name': 'Susan', 'age': 57},
          {'name': 'Carl', 'age': 33})
s = users.select()
rs = s.execute()
row = rs.fetchone()
print 'Id:', row[0]
print 'Name:', row['name']
print 'Age:', row.age
print 'Password:', row[users.c.password]
for row in rs:
    print row.name, 'is', row.age, 'years old
```

It raise error

```
 raise exc.DBAPIError.instance(statement, parameters, e, connection_invalidated=is_disconnect)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' \n\tPRIMARY KEY (user_id)\n)' at line 5") '\nCREATE TABLE users (\n\tuser_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \n\tname VARCHAR(40), \n\tage INTEGER, \n\tpassword VARCHAR, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (user_id)\n)\n\n' ()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This tutorial is for SQLAlchemy version 0.2. Since the actual version is 0.5.7, I'd say the tutorial is severely outdated.

Try the [official](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html) one instead.

---

**EDIT:**

Now you have a completely different question. You should've asked another question instead of editing this one.

Your problem now is that

```
Column('password', String),
```

Doesn't specify a size for the column.

Try

```
Column('password', String(20)),
```

Instead.

Comment: That "official" link is broken

Comment: I think this is the official link at the moment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html

Answer (score 25):

The fix for the tutorial is to just use `MetaData` instead of  `BoundMetaData`. BoundMetaData is deprecated and replaced with MetaData.

And to avoid getting such error in future, Try the [official](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html) one instead,
as `Nosklo` said.

```
from sqlalchemy import *

db = create_engine('sqlite:///tutorial.db')

db.echo = False  # Try changing this to True and see what happens

metadata = MetaData(db)

"""
  Continue with the rest of your Python code
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to specify the length of your `password` field.

```
Column('password', String(100))
```

MySQL does not allow unbounded varchar columns. If you need that, use the sqlalchemy datatype [`Text`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/sqlalchemy/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.Text) instead.